# R/ggplot2: Collapse or remove segment of y-axis from scatter-plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a scatter plot in R with ggplot2, where the middle of the y-axis is collapsed or removed, because there is no data there. I did it in photoshop below, but is there a way to create a similar plot with ggplot?
This is the data with a continuous scale: [image]

But I'm trying to make something like this:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(data=distance_data) +
    geom_point(
        aes(
            x = mdistance,
            y = maxZ,
            shape = factor(subj),
            color = factor(side),
            size = (cSA)
        )
    ) +
    scale_size_continuous(range = c(4, 10)) +
    theme(
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 15),
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black", size= 20, vjust = 0),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "black", size= 20),
        legend.position = "none"
    ) +
    ylab("Z-score") +
    xlab("Distance")
```

Comment: maybe you could insert a break in your y axis (http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html)

Comment: Arbitrary manipulation of scales could be lead to false conclusion.

Comment: @MLavoie I tried using breaks like below but it only changed the tick marks not the dimensions of the plot. scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-6,6), breaks=c(-6,-4,-2,2,4,6))

Comment: @mtoto I agree that is true, but I'm clearly not trying to hide anything. I just want to remove unnecessary space.

Comment: you could use facets.

Comment: Facets don't solve every problem that a broken axis will. You can't use `space = "free"` with `facet_wrap()`, and you can't specify per-facet scales in `facet_grid()`.

This whole argument about broken axes is infuriating to me. Plots aren't misleading, _people_ are misleading. I mean, if I wanted to mislead I would just change the data. 


Also, you can make the same argument about non-linear scales. They're misleading!  A broken axis is a non-linear scale, just like a log scale. 


It's _only_ misleading if you don't know how to read graphs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do this by defining a coordinate transformation. A standard example are logarithmic coordinates, which can be achieved in `ggplot` by using `scale_y_log10()`.

But you can also define custom transformation functions by supplying the `trans` argument to `scale_y_continuous()` (and similarly for `scale_x_continuous()`). To this end, you use the function `trans_new()` from the `scales` package. It takes as arguments the transformation function and its inverse.

I discuss first a special solution for the OP's example and then also show how this can be generalised.

### OP's example

The OP wants to shrink the interval between -2 and 2. The following defines a function (and its inverse) that shrinks this interval by a factor 4:

```
library(scales)
trans <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x > 2, x - 1.5, ifelse(x < -2, x + 1.5, x/4))
}
inv <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x > 0.5, x + 1.5, ifelse(x < -0.5, x - 1.5, x*4))
}
my_trans <- trans_new("my_trans", trans, inv)
```

This defines the transformation. To see it in action, I define some sample data:

```
x_val <- 0:250
y_val <- c(-6:-2, 2:6)
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(x = sample(x_val, 30, replace = TRUE),
                   y = sample(y_val, 30, replace = TRUE))
```

I first plot it without transformation:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-6, 6, by = 2))
```

[image]

Now I use `scale_y_continuous()` with the transformation:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(trans = my_trans,
                       breaks = seq(-6, 6, by = 2))
```

[image]

If you want another transformation, you have to change the definition of `trans()` and `inv()` and run `trans_new()` again. You have to make sure that `inv()` is indeed the inverse of `inv()`. I checked this as follows:

```
x <- runif(100, -100, 100)
identical(x, trans(inv(x)))
## [1] TRUE
```

### General solution

The function below defines a transformation where you can choose the lower and upper end of the region to be squished, as well as the factor to be used. It directly returns the `trans` object that can be used inside `scale_y_continuous`:

```
library(scales)
squish_trans <- function(from, to, factor) {
  
  trans <- function(x) {
    
    if (any(is.na(x))) return(x)

    # get indices for the relevant regions
    isq <- x > from & x < to
    ito <- x >= to
    
    # apply transformation
    x[isq] <- from + (x[isq] - from)/factor
    x[ito] <- from + (to - from)/factor + (x[ito] - to)
    
    return(x)
  }

  inv <- function(x) {
    
    if (any(is.na(x))) return(x)

    # get indices for the relevant regions
    isq <- x > from & x < from + (to - from)/factor
    ito <- x >= from + (to - from)/factor
    
    # apply transformation
    x[isq] <- from + (x[isq] - from) * factor
    x[ito] <- to + (x[ito] - (from + (to - from)/factor))
    
    return(x)
  }
  
  # return the transformation
  return(trans_new("squished", trans, inv))
}
```

The first line in `trans()` and `inv()` handles the case when the transformation is called with `x = c(NA, NA)`. (It seems that this did not happen with the version of `ggplot2` when I originally wrote this question. Unfortunately, I don't know with which version this startet.)

This function can now be used to conveniently redo the plot from the first section:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(trans = squish_trans(-2, 2, 4),
                       breaks = seq(-6, 6, by = 2))
```

The following example shows that you can squish the scale at an arbitrary position and that this also works for other geoms than points:

```
df <- data.frame(class = LETTERS[1:4],
                 val = c(1, 2, 101, 102))
ggplot(df, aes(x = class, y = val)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = squish_trans(3, 100, 50),
                     breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 50, 100, 101, 102))
```

[image]

Let me close by stressing what other already mentioned in comments: this kind of plot could be misleading and should be used with care!

Comment: @Stibu Can the transform you wrote be generalized to work over different ranges? Essentially you are "squishing" the range from -2:2 down to -0.5:0.5. It would seem to me that you could do something similar for an arbitrary range. I have some data I'd like to do this too which has a gap from 2000 to 150,000 I'd like to squish.

I've been trying for an hour or so to modify the function you posted to do this, but I can't get it to work right. I can't find any good documentation/examples for trans_new() which do the kind of piece-wise transformation you are doing here.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Stibu you are a golden, god! My dissertation just got 5% better!

Comment: 5%! I'm not sure that I deserve that much credit even for my own dissertation! ;-) In any case, this was a fun thing to do and I'm glad it helped.

Comment: You also I think have just shown the simplest way forward to finally implement the highly desired, highly controversial "broken axis" in ggplot2.

Comment: I am attempting to use this for a y-scale squish but keep getting the error: `Error in x[isq] <- from + (x[isq] - from) * factor : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments` 

Could this be due to my y-axis being between 0 and 1 (its correlation data)? Any quick modifications I could make to avoid the error? I have verified my data has no NA values and both columns are numeric type. I'd post an example but don't have a big enough character limit in a comment. Thanks!

Comment: @C.John It turns out that the current version of `ggplot2` calls the transformation with `x = c(NA, NA)`, which did not happen with the version that I used when I wrote the question. I have changed the solution such that it also works in this case. Thanks for pointing this out! (And sorry for the long delay...)