# removing unused part of a log-scaled y-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and ggplot and have been trying to remove part of y-axis range for hours and still haven't managed to make it happen. I wrote the following code snippet to make things reproducible in case someone knows the answer. So here is a code snipped:

```
library(ggplot2)
p<- ggplot(data.frame(), aes(color=c("I","Y","I","Y","I","Y"), y=c(75.33,72.95,86.46,79.63,1136.09,993.27), x=c(1,1,2, 2,3, 3))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3),labels = c("A","B","C"))+
  scale_y_log10() +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "l")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+ labs(x = "", y = "")
print(p)
```

And the plot looks like

[image]

I want to remove the y-axis range from 100 to 900 to help with the visibility of the values below 100. I have already tried [this](https://rpubs.com/huanfaChen/squash_remove_y_axix_ggplot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511951/r-ggplot2-collapse-or-remove-segment-of-y-axis-from-scatter-plot) but neither of them work (I get weird NA erros, etc). Would appreciate a help.

Comment: The whole point of a plot is that the distance between points are interpretable. If you remove a chunk of your axis, you are violating that basic rule. The connecting line would be meaningless. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yes, unless there is a way to show the lost information for those values that are squashed between 0-100. To be more clear, the purpose of this plot is not to compare A, B, C. It is to compare the blue and red line on setting A, setting B, setting C.

Answer (score 2):

How about this as an alternative, if you're looking to emphasize the blue and red within each setting?

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, color = color)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y, ymax = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~x, scales = "free") +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+ 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

input data

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  color=c("I","Y","I","Y","I","Y"),
  y = c(75.33,72.95,86.46,79.63,1136.09,993.27),
  x= c(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not a big fan of the "squishing" with user-defined transformations. Logarithmic scales cause already enough pain for some analysts / readers.
I support @Jon's approach using facets and `scale_free`. However, one of the posts that you pointed to provides an interesting example and defines a `generic squish_trans` function` which was fun to test. Just adapt things properly!

Kudos to @Stibu for developing and sharing the `squish_trans()` function. Check out [R/ggplot2: Collapse or remove segment of y-axis from scatter-plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511951/r-ggplot2-collapse-or-remove-segment-of-y-axis-from-scatter-plot) for more details.

Key points to note: work with `scale_y_continuous()` and set visually appealing breaks.

```
library(ggplot2)

p<- ggplot(data.frame(), aes(color=c("I","Y","I","Y","I","Y"),     y=c(75.33,72.95,86.46,79.63,1136.09,993.27), x=c(1,1,2, 2,3, 3))) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point()+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3),labels = c("A","B","C")) +
#--------------- apply squish_trans to scale_y_continuous --------------------
# settings chosen: lower bound = 200, upper bound 900
# defining breaks to show on graph and 
# setting limits to "force" a top level tick (this is not strictly necessary, but  looks better ... I think)
    scale_y_continuous( trans  = squish_trans(200, 900, 100)
                       ,breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200)
                       ,limits = c(0, 1200)
    ) +
#-------------- remove the additional log-based ticks
# commented out to show
    #  annotation_logticks(sides = "l")  +

    theme(legend.position = "none")+ labs(x = "", y = "")

# print plot
p
```

This yields:

[image]