# Remove part of Y axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to apply [R/ggplot2: Collapse or remove segment of y-axis from scatter-plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511951/r-ggplot2-collapse-or-remove-segment-of-y-axis-from-scatter-plot) to remove values from 25 to 75 from my plot's y axis.
However i do not get the result desired when I have grouped plot. 
what is the best way to squeeze part of y axis to make plots clear.

```
library(scales)
squish_trans <- function(from, to, factor) {
  
  trans <- function(x) {
    
    if (any(is.na(x))) return(x)

    # get indices for the relevant regions
    isq <- x > from & x < to
    ito <- x >= to
    
    # apply transformation
    x[isq] <- from + (x[isq] - from)/factor
    x[ito] <- from + (to - from)/factor + (x[ito] - to)
    
    return(x)
  }

  inv <- function(x) {
    
    if (any(is.na(x))) return(x)

    # get indices for the relevant regions
    isq <- x > from & x < from + (to - from)/factor
    ito <- x >= from + (to - from)/factor
    
    # apply transformation
    x[isq] <- from + (x[isq] - from) * factor
    x[ito] <- to + (x[ito] - (from + (to - from)/factor))
    
    return(x)
  }
  
  # return the transformation
  return(trans_new("squished", trans, inv))
}

df <- data.frame(state = factor(c("CA", "NY", "TX", "CA", "NY", "CA", "NY", "TX")),
                 value = c(2,5,4,8,9,7,4,6),
                 rangeL = c(1,4,3,7,8,5,3,5),
                 rangeU = c(4,7,5,9,10,9,100,70),
                 grp = factor(c("x", "x","x","y", "y","z","z","z")))
df

df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=state, y= value, color = grp, group = grp)) +
    geom_point(position=position_dodge(.7)) +
    geom_errorbar(ymin = df$rangeL, ymax= df$rangeU, position=position_dodge(.7), width = 0.5) +
    expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
    ylim(0, max(df$rangeU)) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = squish_trans(25, 75, 10),
                     breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 20, 25, 75, 100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your trans function. It's the way that you are using `geom_errorbar` that is problematic. Since, for some reason, you are not mapping the `ymin` and `ymax` aesthetics to the appropriate columns, but instead passing them as geom parameters outside of `aes`, they are not being used when calculating the correct range for the panel.

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=state, y= value, color = grp, group = grp)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(.7)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = rangeL, ymax= rangeU), 
                position=position_dodge(.7), width = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = squish_trans(25, 75, 10),
                     breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 20, 25, 75, 100))
```

[image]