# Axis labels don't display properly when applying multiple transformations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to take the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511951/r-ggplot2-collapse-or-remove-segment-of-y-axis-from-scatter-plot) and make a function that generates a transformation to shrink an arbitrary number of regions along the x axis. I got the data to compress how I want it to but can't figure out how to get the axis labels right. I suspect the issue is with how I actually composed the transformations in the final function.

First, I broke the original function into two chunks:

```
trans_builder <- function(from, to, factor){
  trans <- function(x){
    if (any(is.na(x))) return(x)
    # get indices for the relevant regions
    isq <- x > from & x < to
    ito <- x >= to
    
    # apply transformation
    x[isq] <- from + (x[isq] - from)/factor
    x[ito] <- from + (to - from)/factor + (x[ito] - to)
    
    return(x)
  }
  return(trans)
}

inv_builder <- function(from, to, factor){
  inv <- function(x){
    if (any(is.na(x))) return(x)
    
    # get indices for the relevant regions
    isq <- x > from & x < from + (to - from)/factor
    ito <- x >= from + (to - from)/factor
    
    # apply transformation
    x[isq] <- from + (x[isq] - from) * factor
    x[ito] <- to + (x[ito] - (from + (to - from)/factor))
    
    return(x)
  }
  return(inv)
}
```

I also wrote a function to sort the input bounds in a certain way (won't go into why right now because I don't think it's relevant to this problem):

```
sort_bounds <- function(shrinkbounds){
  from <- c()
  to <- c()
  if(length(shrinkbounds > 0)){
    for(i in 1:(length(shrinkbounds)/2)){
      from <- append(from, shrinkbounds[2*i-1])
      to <- append(to, shrinkbounds[2*i])
    }
    from_order <- order(from, decreasing = TRUE)
    to_order <- order(to, decreasing = TRUE)
    if(identical(from_order, to_order)){
      shrink_out <- c()
      for(i in 1:(length(shrinkbounds)/2)){
        shrink_out <- append(shrink_out, from[from_order[i]])
        shrink_out <- append(shrink_out, to[to_order[i]])
      }
      return(shrink_out)
    }
  }
  return(shrinkbounds)
}
```

Finally, the function I ended up with:

```
shrink_trans <- function(shrinkbounds, factor){
  shrinkbounds <- sort_bounds(shrinkbounds)
  trans_final <- trans_builder(shrinkbounds[1], shrinkbounds[2], factor)
  inv_final <- inv_builder(shrinkbounds[1], shrinkbounds[2], factor)
  
  if(length(shrinkbounds) > 2){
    for (i in 2:(length(shrinkbounds)/2)){
      transi <- trans_builder(shrinkbounds[2*i-1], shrinkbounds[2*i], factor)
      invi <- trans_builder(shrinkbounds[2*i-1], shrinkbounds[2*i], factor)
      
      trans_int <- trans_final
      inv_int <- inv_final
      
      trans_final <- function(x) return(transi(trans_int(x)))
      inv_final <- function(x) return(inv_int(invi(x)))
    }
  }
  return(trans_new('shrink_trans', trans_final, inv_final))
}
```

The idea is that shrinkbounds is a vector listing out the boundaries of the regions you want shrunk (i.e. c(1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10) to shrink between 1 and 5, 6 and 8, and 9 and 10) and factor specifies how much you want the axis shrunk. Now, running the function on a test dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:50, y = runif(50))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off', xlim = c(1, 50)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:50, labels = 1:50, trans = shrink_trans(c(1, 20, 30, 50), 20), expand = c(0, 0))
```

Output Graph

[image: Output graph]

As you can see, there are two clusters of data at either end, but the only x axis tick showing up is 1. Why is that?

I tried adding an argument xbreaks to the shrink_trans function so I could set the breaks argument in trans_new as `trans_new('shrink_trans', trans_final, inv_final, breaks = xbreaks)`, but that made no difference.

Comment: The main issue (and you're going to say...ahhh mannnn! whatever! All this work and that happened...) in `shrink_trans`'s `if` you have `transi <- trans_builder...` followed by `invi <- trans_builder`...pretty sure you meant `invi <- inv_builder`.  I'm not exactly sure why, but `expand` is causing an issue with the axis labels, as well. Ideally, you might have the breaks in `scale_x_continuous` set to `c(1, 20, 25, 30, 50)`. You won't be able to fit a marker at `1:50` when you shrink the scale to 1/20 at the edges. Since these are values, don't use `labels` (just `breaks`). Questions?

Comment: Ah, you're right! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your code using `approx`, which will allow you to define `shrink_trans` like this:

```r
shrink_trans <- function(bounds, factor) {
  
  if(length(bounds) < 2 | !is.numeric(bounds) | length(bounds) %% 2 == 1) 
    stop('Need an even number of numeric bounds')
  bounds <- sort(bounds)
  outmap <- cumsum(c(bounds[1], 
           diff(bounds) / rep(c(factor, 1), length = length(bounds) - 1)))
  
  fix_bounds <- function(x) {
    if(min(x) < min(bounds)) {
      bounds <- c(min(x), bounds)
      outmap <- c(min(x), outmap)
    }
    if(max(x) > max(bounds)) {
      bounds <- c(bounds, max(x))
      outmap <- c(outmap, tail(diff(bounds), 1) + tail(outmap, 1))
    }
    list(bounds = bounds, outmap = outmap)
  }
  
  tranfun <- function(x) {
    with(fix_bounds(x), approx(bounds, outmap, xout = x)$y)
  }
  
  invfun <- function(x) {
    with(fix_bounds(x), approx(outmap, bounds, xout = x)$y)
  }
  
  scales::trans_new('shrink_trans', tranfun, invfun)
}
```

Then your plotting code produces:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:50, y = runif(50))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off', xlim = c(1, 50)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 10, 20:30, 40, 50),
                     trans = shrink_trans(c(1, 20, 30, 50), 20), 
                     expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

And we can test it works with other values for `bounds` and `factor`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off', xlim = c(0, 50)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:10 * 5,
                     trans = shrink_trans(seq(5, 55, 10), 5), 
                     expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice function, but I'm getting an error when the bounds don't go up to the maximum x value. So, for example, in this dataset trans = shrink_trans(seq(5, 55, 10), 5) works as you showed above but trans = shrink_trans(seq(5, 35, 10), 5) gives the error "Error in if (zero_range(as.numeric(limits))) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed." Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Ended up resolving the issue by adding a new function fix_bounds2 with bounds and outmap flipped to use in invfun.